# How to invent a code for square-root?

Tags: c

I want to write a code for making square-root not using pow().
here is what i have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a,I,sum=0,cnt=0;
    printf("enter number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(I=1;sum<a;I+=2){
        sum+=I;
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("answer is:%d",cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

for numbers like 4,9,16,... it works but for numbers like 10,17,21,.. it does not work and the result is more than it shoud be.
what is the problem?

Comment: By "radical with root 2", do you just mean "square root"?

Comment: I would suggest writing that then!  Everyone knows what it means; most people don't know what "radical with root 2" means.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: the problem is sum<a.it count one more when I enter (10 for example) but I don't know how to change it to get the correct result.

Comment: read it here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/square-root-of-a-perfect-square/

Comment: @RC. You may be referring to a famous inverse square root floating-point implementation that was fast in the early 2000s. That won't do the OP much good, as the OP is trying to compute a square root of integers (though that may change as the OP's objectives become clearer)

Comment: `it does not work and the result is more than it shoud be.` What makes you think that this code intended to compute it? You should be aware that square root of 10, 17, 21 is not an integer but rather fractional. In your code `cnt` will always be an integer.

Comment: I didn't want the exact answer.I need a round number.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't really understand what your code does. It finds the smallest number whose square is greater than or equal to the target value. That's why it overshoots for values which are not perfect squares -- because that's what you told it to do. If you want the nearest integer then you need to make an appropriate adjustment to your loop control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a,I,cnt=0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("enter number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(I=1;sum<a;I+=2){
    sum+=I;
    cnt++;

    if(sum > a)     //add this if statement to decrement cnt by 1 when sum exceeds a.
        cnt--;

    }
   printf("answer is:%d",cnt);
}
```

Input:

```
21
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a,I,sum=0,cnt=0;
    printf("enter number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(I=1;sum<a;I+=2){
        sum+=I;
        cnt++;
    }
    if(sum==a)
        printf("answer is:%d",cnt);
    else
        printf("answer is:%d",cnt-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    for(I=1;;I+=2){
        sum+=I;
        if(sum>a)  
              break;
        cnt++;
    }
```

Comment: Something wrong with your keyboard's spacebar? Or maybe poor readability FTW?

Comment: @ddriver This answer fixes the program from the question. It could also fix the presentation of the program from the question, but that would distract from the main contribution. The OP did not ask how code should be presented.

Comment: @PascalCuoq But honestly, don't you think this indentation is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Babylonian method:

```
double babyl_sqrt(double x)
{
    double i;
    for (i = x / 2; fabs(i * i - x) > 0.000001f; i = (i + x / i) / 2)
        ;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Very soon I am expecting to here [Harappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harappa) and Roman methods!

Answer (score 0):

To get a *rounded to nearest `int`*, adjust the limit a little bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int sqrt_round(int a) {
  int I;
  int sum = 0;
  int cnt = 0;
  // for(I=1;sum<a;I+=2){
  for (I = 1; (sum + I / 2) < a; I += 2) {
    sum += I;
    cnt++;
  }
  return cnt;
}

int main() {
  int a;
  printf("enter number");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("answer is:%d\n", sqrt_round(a));
  printf("answer is:%g\n", sqrt(a));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        float  i,x=10;
        int lp;
        scanf("%f",&i);
        for(lp=0;lp<5;lp++)
        x=(x-((((x*x)-i))/(2*x)));
        printf("sqaure root of %f=%f\n",i,x);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute and return the square root of x, where x is guaranteed to be a non-negative integer.

Since the return type is an integer, the decimal digits are truncated and only the integer part of the result is returned.

Example 1:

**Input: 4
Output: 2**

Example 2:

**Input: 8
Output: 2**

Explanation: The square root of 8 is 2.82842..., and since 
             the decimal part is truncated, 2 is returned.

```
public int mySqrt(int x) {
    long start = 1;
    long end = x;

    while(start + 1< end) {
        long mid = start + (end - start) / 2 ;
        if(mid * mid == x) { 
            return (int)mid;
        }else if(mid * mid < x) {
            start = mid ;
        }else {
            end = mid;
        }
    }

    if(end * end == x) {
        return (int)end;
    }

    return (int)start;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Kindly read guidelines of stackoverflow and modify your answer. As you need to explain the Answer as well, Posting only code is not a good approach.

Comment: Hi Intsab , sorry for inconvenience. Now I have elaborated it.